# Remove "Set Optimal Settings" message

Tags: windows-7, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

How can I get rid of the message that pops up sometimes when starting Call of Duty 4 - Multiplayer?

> Your computer appears to have changed since the last time you ran Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare.
>   Would you like the game to configure itself optimally for your new hardware?
>
> This is recommended for most people.
>   It will change your system settings but not your controls.

[image: Popup message]

I have tried these different solutions, none of them works:

- Remove the lines corresponding to the message in the `C:\Program Files\Activision\Call of Duty 4 - Modern Warfare\localization.txt` file:
  [image: Screenshot of localization.txt file]
- Make the `config_mp.cfg` file flagged as read-only (it was originally).
- Make the `config_mp.cfg` file *not* flagged as read-only.

I have a sense that this message is linked to the `sys_configSum` variable located in the `config_mp.cfg` file, because sometimes this variable is equal to `"0"`, and some other times to `"4379996"`, but I can't figure why it changes.

Any other ideas?

PS: I do *not* use Steam.
PPS: The `config_mp.cfg` file is located under `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Activision\Call of Duty 4 - Modern Warfare\players\profiles\[profile]` for me.

Comment: I'd recommend uninstalling the game and reinstall it in a different location outside of the Program Files directory. Any program that writes to files in the installation directory will have issues (i.e., will need to be run as administrator) and COD4 definitely writes to it. My guess is that the settings detection isn't detecting the right settings because it either can't run the right privileged instructions to get the right info, or it can't write the settings to the right files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. Every time you join to a server. Do not quit the game using the command "/quit". Instead of this, press ESC -> Disconnect, and to main menu press quit button. Doing this, next time you connect to call of duty 4, you don't see anymore the pop-up. The /quit command is a "forced close" of the game, and causes to appear the pop-up.

Cheers.

Comment: I always do `ESC -> Disconnect -> Quit`.